# Prevent automatic passing of URL parameter in Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, parameter-passing, url-routing, razor-pages

I'm using the .NET Core 2 "Razor Pages" format for a web app. It allows you to define how to map the URL to variable names with a simple directive at the top:

```
@page "{personId:int?}"
```

The above, for example, would map the URL `/Person/Index/123` to the `IndexModel.OnGetAsync(int personId)` function so that `personId` would have a value of 123.

However, I've noticed that these values seem to be automatically added to any URL they could be, if a link exists on the page. If I add the following to the Index page:

```
<a asp-page="/Person/Details">Details</a>
```

…the actual HTML that's generated is:

```
<a href="/Person/Details/123">Details</a>
```

…meaning that because both the Index and Details pages have the same directive at the top, the value of `personId` is implicitly passed between them.

Is there any way to prevent this, so that `asp-page="/Person/Details"` would simply redirect to the Details page without any value passed for `personId`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `Asp.Net Core`, the current route values of the current request are considered ambient values for link generation.

For your scenario, 123 for `personId` will be reused for `<a asp-page="/Person/Details">Details</a>` link generation.

From this url generation process, you could try to remove the value from `RouteData`

```
        public async Task OnGetAsync(int? personId)
    {
        Person = await _context.Person.ToListAsync();
        RouteData.Values.Remove("personId");
    }
```

For another better way, you could try to remove the value from url generation.

```
<a asp-page="/Person/Details" asp-route-personId="">Details</a>
```