# Prevent ambient route values from the URL from being added to Html.Action and Html.ActionLinks automatically in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, routes

In my ASP.NET Core 2.1 project, I've noticed that my `Html.ActionLinks` and `Html.Actions`, that do not have an `id` set, are automatically including the `id` from the current URL.

For example, given the following `Html.ActionLink` in a view:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Apply Online", "Apply-Online", "Careers")</li>
```

If the URL of the current page is `localhost:1234/careers/apply-online/53`, then when I inspect the `href` of the above `Html.ActionLink` in my navigation, it includes the "53" in the generated URL (even though it wasn't set in my view).

I can prevent this from happening if I explicitly set the `id` to nothing, like this:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Apply Online", "Apply-Online", "Careers", new { id = "" })</li>
```

However, is there a way to stop this across the board without having to update all my action links?

I'm getting weird behavior, where if two controllers have the same action name (such as `Index`) and the URL for one has an `id`, it adds the same `id` to all of the other actions with a matching name on the page.

Here's my routing in `Startup.cs`:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

**UPDATE**

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/fundamentals/routing.md), it appears to be `AmbientValues` that is causing this behavior:

> The second parameter to the VirtualPathContext constructor is a
>   collection of ambient values. Ambient values provide convenience by
>   limiting the number of values a developer must specify within a
>   certain request context. The current route values of the current
>   request are considered ambient values for link generation. In an
>   ASP.NET Core MVC app if you are in the About action of the
>   HomeController, you don't need to specify the controller route value
>   to link to the Index action—the ambient value of Home is used.
>
> Ambient values that don't match a parameter are ignored, and ambient
>   values are also ignored when an explicitly provided value overrides
>   it, going from left to right in the URL.

So this seems to explain why, I can prevent the `id` from being automatically set if I explicitly set it to `{ id = "" }` in my `Html.ActionLink`.

My question is, is there a way to set `id` to not use ambient values by default, perhaps in my `MapRoute`? And only use the `id` if it is explicitly set to a value in an `Action` or `ActionLink`?

Comment: Have you tried with `<a asp-controller="Careers" asp-action="Apply-Online">Apply Online</a>`?

Comment: Try to check my answer on [Prevent automatic passing of URL parameter in Razor Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52687932/prevent-automatic-passing-of-url-parameter-in-razor-pages/52694854#52694854). For another way, you could try `Route("[action]")` to specify the controller action without `id`.

Comment: Hi Tao, your answer was helpful to show why it was happening with the ambient values. Assuming there isn't a way to override the ambient behavior for a specific route value, such as `id`, then it looks like setting `Route("[action]")` will be the next best thing. Please feel free to write that up in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [TagHelpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.1) ?

TagHelpers remplace HtmlHelpers, they are more readable and easy to use.

For example, with HtmlHelpers the links were written like that:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Apply Online", "Apply-Online", "Careers")
```

It's remplaced by...

```
<a asp-area="" asp-controller="Careers" asp-action="Apply-Online"
asp-route-id="53" 
asp-route-toto="foo">
    Apply Online
</a>
<!-- expected: /Careers/Apply-Online/53?toto=foo -->
```

Obviously, if you remove asp-route-id, "53" is removed and if you remove asp-route-toto, the query string is removed too.