# Url.Action method is returning wrong url string

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to use the following code to generate url string:

```
var x = @Url.Action("AddOrEditSaleOffer", "BuildingOffers", null);
```

However, the returned value somehow generates the the following url:

```
/BuildingOffers/AddOrEditSaleOffer/7
```

where 7 is a number that changes based on the id of the last edited Offer.

The code is in a partial view and is called using ajax call and after making an edit to the Building Offer record. I am expecting to get NO id but the url is appending an id somehow.

**UPDATE:**

I found the following question helpful to understand why I was facing this problem and also suggested work arounds: [Prevent ambient route values from the URL from being added to Html.Action and Html.ActionLinks automatically in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52747626/prevent-ambient-route-values-from-the-url-from-being-added-to-html-action-and-ht)

Also, the following section in Microsoft Docs. discusses this issue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#url-generation-reference

Comment: what happens if you omit the `null` parameter?

Comment: I get the same result as if null was present. (The id is still passed).

Comment: The weird thing is that it works properly the first time generated, but when I call that page using ajax call after editing a record, it passes the id of the record I just updated.

Comment: Why dont use just  var x = " /BuildingOffers/AddOrEditSaleOffer" ???

Comment: @Sergey using `Url.Action` is considered more robust. The route pattern might change and a literal string would then break, while `Url.Action` generates the correct url.

Comment: I am sorry but eou can even try to use a string builder to make it  more complicated. I don't see any robust here since yout use the same raw strings and names of the actions can't be changed as well as anything else.

Comment: Can you share more core: html & ajax?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to send parameters in your url, you can use the other Action method overload, which takes controller and action as input parameters.

```
var url = @Url.Action("AddOrEditSaleOffer", "BuildingOffers");
```

Comment: I tried this but produced the same output. (It still passed the id of the previous edited record ).

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like this

```
 string url = " /controllerName/ActionName
```

:)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I think this might solve the issue but I want to know why my code does not work.

Comment: As pointed in the comments above: "The route pattern might change and a literal string would then break, while Url.Action generates the correct url."

Comment: in Action function that you use the description is: Generate URL with specific route value, maybe this is for it.
please if the answer is useful, please rate.