# Un-setting route parameters in razorpages pages

Tags: razor-pages, urlhelper

I have a page `Index` that has two optional parameters: `FolderId` and `OrganisationId`.

If I use `@page "{OrganisationId:int?}/{FolderId:int?}"` at the start of the razorpages page to make nicer URLs then it becomes impossible to remove a parameter from the URL. The behaviour of the URL helpers changes.

For example the browser is at `/Index/1/4` and I want to make a link to `/Index/1`. The code for the link ought to be

```
<a asp-area="Files" asp-page="/Index" asp-route-OrganisationId="@Model.Organisation.Id">@Model.Organisation.Name</a>
```

This works for `@page`, producing the required `/Index/`.

However, if the razorpages page begins with `@page "{OrganisationId:int?}/{FolderId:int?}"` then instead this renders `/Index/1/4` which is clearly wrong because it is not what was asked for.

I have tried `asp-route-FolderId=""` and using `asp-route-all-data` but the unwanted parameter still appears.

Is it possible to get URL helpers to work correctly with the route templates?

Comment: If you are using Razor Pages 2.2 or lower, you might be running into a side effect of ambient values: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52687932/prevent-automatic-passing-of-url-parameter-in-razor-pages

Comment: Ta; that has worked to remove the unwanted value.

Is that really the best solution? It seems rather unsatisfactory.

Comment: Yep, that's probably part of the reason why they removed ambient values in 3.0